# need help with certification practice exam grading formula

Tags: arithmetic

**Since i'm being trolled with negative marks on my post without people even giving any kind of constructive feedback, other than Rolazaro, I'm re-writing the question:**

I am creating a program for a friend of mine that runs a technical college to write / practice / take exams for certifications and other tests. My problem is that I am not very mathematically inclined and need help with the formula for calculating the point average for each question based on three factors:

- the difficulty of the question (values 1-10, 10 being hardest)
- the total number of questions in the test (between 10 to 250+)
- the total points possible, regardless of the number of questions (1,000 points)

The problem that i'm having is that I cannot find a way to factor in two of the variables so that the total possible score will always be 1,000:

- the total number of questions on the test (let's call it "Qi", (i) represents the question #)
- the difficulty rating of the question (let's call it "D")

Can anyone *PLEASE* help me with this? I really am struggling to figure out a formula for this...

Comment: The given example, if properly extended, works for any amount of questions. Try replacing "Dividing 500" by "Dividing 1000", and so on. Play with it, try to understand, why it works as it works. How would you use this numbers (as variables) in a program? Then tell us as exactly as possible what is not working for you.

Comment: sorry, the problem exists with the 500/1000. one of those two should be the maximum point value for the questions (it doesn't matter if its 10 questions or 1,000 questions). If I were to give 250 questions at an average difficulty of 5, the total points would exceed 1,000 (1,250). so if the student manages to get a perfect score, the score would look like "1,250/1,000" which is not good. I need a way to divide the total score of 1,000 by both the number of questions and the difficulty of said question... but i can't figure out how :(

Comment: lower the score for each question?

Comment: Rolazaro, just lowering the score for each question will not achieve the goal i'm after and would cause more work. the scores cannot be a static variable, they must be dynamic - always changing based on the number of questions and difficulty of each question. That is why i'm trying to figure out the formula for this. The total score for all questions must be 1,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry everyone.

It seems that my difficulty was all due to a mistake I made on my excel sheet calculation.

My original error with the 1250/1000 was due to my having missed multiplying the student score (1250) by the point average, which was calculated by the sum of the question difficulties divided by 1,000 - which for 1250 would give me about ~0.8.

After summing up the difficulty ratings of correctly answered questions (for example, 1020) and multiplying by 0.8 - it would give me the correct score out of a total 1,000.

```
1000/1250 = 0.8 point average
1020 sum of student's correct question difficulties
1020*0.8 = 816 of 1000 final score, or 82% when up-rounded
```